# Android Studio project: How to combine java class constructor into my existing public class extends fragment?

Tags: java, android

```
//public constructor
public class Hero {

    private String name;
    private String realname;
    private String team;
    private String firstappearance;
    private String createdby;
    private String publisher;
    private String imageurl;
    private String bio;

    public Hero(String name, String realname, String team, String firstappearance, String createdby, String publisher, String imageurl, String bio) {
        this.name = name;
        this.realname = realname;
        this.team = team;
        this.firstappearance = firstappearance;
        this.createdby = createdby;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
        this.bio = bio;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getRealname() {
        return realname;
    }

    public String getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public String getFirstappearance() {
        return firstappearance;
    }

    public String getCreatedby() {
        return createdby;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public String getImageurl() {
        return imageurl;
    }

    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }


}

//to put into PresentFragment java class 
public class PresentFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_present, null);
    }
}
```

I would like to use Hero REST data to view in my fragment page. I have tried but it errors in here.

```
//MainActivity
case R.id.navigation_present:
                fragment = new PresentFragment();
                break;
```

I also have done codes for the Main activity, and API interface.

Comment: Would you please describe the problem clearly?

Comment: Okay. Right now I am using bottom navigation view for my project. The problem occurred when I do not know how to put data or anything into my fragments. I hv tried so many example from youtube but cannot view it. Is there any references or notes  that I can refer to get more understanding about fragments / bottom navigation